# why my price is not showing while adding new product?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

[image: price not showing]

while adding new product why it is not showing the option to enter the price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top right, click on `Screen Options` and then select the `Product Data` checkbox.

[image]